# Citrix API Ajax call in Angular is not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, api, citrix

I am unable to convert the below ajax call into ANGULARJS. I've used ng-click to call the function but internally I've called the JavaScript AJAX method which intern calls API.

```
$scope.create = function () {

    console.log("clicked");
    setMeetingData();
    $scope.esub = meetingData["subject"];
    var url = "https://api.citrixonline.com/G2M/rest/meetings";
    HTTPRequest(url, "POST", meetingData);

}


function HTTPRequest(serviceUrl, httpRequestMethod, content) {
    try {
        var postData = "";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open(httpRequestMethod, serviceUrl, false);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_token=" + accessToken);
        if (typeof content !== undefined) {
            postData = JSON.stringify(content);
        }
        console.info("Request(" + httpRequestMethod + "): " + serviceUrl);
        xmlhttp.send(postData);
        console.info("Result:(" + xmlhttp.status + ")", xmlhttp.responseText);

        //HTTP response code treatment, incomplete
        var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        msgBox.innerHTML = "You successfully created a Meeting! This is your join URL: &#10;" + result[0]["joinURL"] + "&#10;and the meeting id: &#10;" + result[0]["meetingid"]            

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.info("Error: ", err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whenever you want to perform http-request, [`$http service`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is a tool you need

Comment: is that a directive to be added?
    `App.controller('MeetCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
.............
.............
}`

Comment: Service is not a directive. Moreover, directives are not injectable. Anyway, your understanding is correct, you have to inject `$http` into controller.